# Save pane configurations / sessions in atom

Tags: session, configuration, atom-editor, pane

Usually I see myself developing a component in react, for example, and every time I edit this component I need to edit also related files like `css` ones or inner `components`. I, moreover, like to have this files organized in different panes, see the image for an example. Do you know if, while working in my project, can I open/close this whole pane/files configurations? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: any luck on this? I'd love to have exactly that functionality

Answer (score 1):

How about this: https://atom.io/packages/save-workspace. I don't think it is quite what you were looking for but it should work - instead of providing tab configurations for a specific project, it keeps a global set of configurations including open project directories, tab/pane configurations, and active cursors.